AWS CloudFront Temporary Error 403 AccessDenied to S3
I am hosting a react app on AWS using AWS CloudFront and AWS S3.
Specifically, the S3 contains the built react app code. The bucket itself doesn't use S3 Static website hosting: instead, the files of the bucket should be available to CloudFront, since the Bucket policy looks similar to this:
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::react-app/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:distribution/xxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

The CloudFront distribution has an origin that looks like this:
Origin name: react-app.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Origin domain: react-app.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Origin type: S3

The website seems to be successfully hosted and working. However sometimes (for example when I try to do a Lighthouse scan), CloudFront returns, rather than the actual page, an error that looks like this:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>AAF5Y58QHZEAR6BS</RequestId>
<HostId>Z7/3LgKA4JAQMwuzsgIQqRop37/f70H8sdZxZIcpZTKJCYZUDgFHds5jnPxZPbPEea466qwH8OY=</HostId>
</Error>

The error goes away whether I refresh the page or I navigate to another URL. Why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.
